# Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, lighttpd, self-signed-certificate

Tried starting Lighttpd after editing it:

```
@raspberrypi:/etc/lighttpd/ssl $ systemctl status lighttpd.service
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-01-10 14:36:35 CET; 11s ago
    Process: 17057 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
        CPU: 60ms

Jan 10 14:36:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 10 14:36:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Jan 10 14:36:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 10 14:36:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 10 14:36:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
```

And here is what I edited in the conf file:

```
$SERVER ["socket"] == ":443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/buildinggroup6.local.pem"
      # ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/CA_issuing.crt"
        server.name = "group6.local"
        server.document-root = "/sites/vhosts/group6.local/public"
        server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/group6.local.error.log"
        accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/group6.local.access.log"
}
```

I have tried nothing, it was supposed to start and after editing it give me a ssl certificate for my web server.

Answer (score 0):

Manually run the `ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` step on the command line and look at the errors.  systemd tends to hide useful information in noise.

Run this manually: `/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and fix the configuration errors reported by lighttpd.

My guess is that you specified `ssl.pemfile` but that you also need to specify `ssl.privkey` with the path to the private key for the TLS certificate.

Comment: Whenever I use `/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` I get this:
`2023-01-11 09:56:07: configfile.c.2274) server.upload-dirs doesn't exist: /var/cache/lighttpd/uploads
2023-01-11 09:56:07: plugin.c.195) dlopen() failed for: /usr/lib/lighttpd/mod_openssl.so /usr/lib/lighttpd/mod_openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-01-11 09:56:07: server.c.1238) loading plugins finally failed`

Comment: What do those errors mean to you?  Did you get the hint that you need to take some action?  For the directory that does not exist, did it occur to you that you should create that directory, and give lighttpd permission to write there?  For the missing file (mod_openssl.so), did it occur to you that you might have to install a package to obtain the missing file?  `sudo apt-get install lighttpd-mod-openssl`